# Output a count number in foreach loop to show proper row number

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

What's the best practice to output the each row's real counter from an array ? I have the object array of retrieved users from database that I'am echoing into the `<table />`

```
<tbody>
    <?php $i = 1;?>
    <?php foreach($members as $member):?>
    <tr>
        <td class="column-counter">
            <?php echo $i;?>
        </td>
        <td class="column-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checked[]" value="<?php echo $member->id;?>" <?php if(intval($member->id) === intval($this->session->userdata('login_status')['id'])):?>disabled<?php endif;?>>
        </td>
        <td class="column-username">
            <?php echo $member->username;?>
        </td>
        <td class="column-email">
            <a href="#send-email"><?php echo $member->email;?></a>
        </td>
        <td class="column-id">
            <?php echo $member->id;?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php $i++;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</tbody>
```

What I've done so far is that `$i =1` incrementing each time the loop is triggered.

But the problem is that if I go to the second page, it starts from "1" again, instead of let's say `21` (in case it shows 20 rows per page).

How can I make it right so it will continue counting from last row of previous page ?

By the way I'am using a codeigniter if that helps.

**==== UPDATE ====**

The model `models/members_model.php` i'am using in `controllers/members.php` to retrieve the users holds this function mixed with pagination:

```
public function members($data = array(), $return_count = FALSE){

    $this->db
        ->select('
            members.id,
            categories.title as role,
            members.catid as role_id,
            members.firstname,
            members.lastname,
            members.username,
            members.email,
            members.status,
            members.image
        ')
        ->join('categories', 'members.catid = categories.id');

    if( empty($data) ){
        // If nothing provided, return everything
        $this->get_members();
    }else{
        // Grab the offset
        if( !empty($data['page']) ){
            $this->db->offset($data['page']);
        }

        // Grab the limit
        if( !empty($data['items']) ){
            $this->db->limit($data['items']);
        }

        if( $return_count ){
            return $this->db->count_all_results($this->_table_name);
        }else{
            return $this->db->get($this->_table_name)->result();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You have some logic in your code to determine the next 20, maybe that you use in your SQL LIMIT clause?  You would use that.

Comment: @AbraCadaver - I'am sorry but I didn't get what you've tried to say. Please, could you explain in another way ?

Comment: When you display only 20 results per page, how do you do that?  You somehow query for 20, display and then when the next page is clicked you query for the next 20 and display etc?  Unless that is what you are asking?  That's called pagination and I thought you had that sorted.

Comment: I've updated my question, could you please check it, there is a `$this->db->limit($data['items']);` which limits the results. What Can i do with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `$data['page']` holds the information you need since this is related to the specified offset. You didn't reference the name of this array in your global scope, so I will just call this `$data_array` in my answer.

You can determine the starting value for `$i` as follows

```
$i = $data_array['page'] + 1;
```

Comment: Maan, i have dilemma in my head, will be back once I'll solve this. Thanks for tip

Comment: Thanks I got that by now.